# How can I block IE 9 using WSUS?

Tags: internet-explorer, wsus, internet-explorer-9

We use WSUS on our LAN. We have to complete some testing before I can let users upgrade to IE 9.

I would like to <strike>block it</strike> prevent it from being auto-installed until testing is complete.

The Microsoft document [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/gg615599) refers me to [KB 946202](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946202).

However, the information in KB 946202 seems dated and vague. Basically it tells you to disallow automatic approval of Update Rollup packages.

I have the following questions:

- Is there a better way to block IE 9 using WSUS?
- Will turning off auto-approval of Update Rollups block IE 9? I never would have guessed that a browser upgrade is an “Update Rollup.”
- What other effects will this have? Will we be missing other important updates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, temporarily disabling Update Rollups is the way to do it.

You won't really be missing out on anything - it will still download the update rollups metadata, it just won't automatically approve them. Once the IE9 metadata has downloaded to your WSUS server, you can switch the auto-approval of update rollups back on if you so desire (personally the only thing I auto-approve is definition updates though).

It won't *block* Internet Explorer 9, per se but what it will allow you to do is either approve it for a subset of users (a test group for example) or just leave it unapproved for the time being until you do decide to deploy it.

Comment: Good point about blocking. I don’t need to block it, just stop it from being auto-approved so this sounds like the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting the specific IE9 package/update and setting it to Not Approved.

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to deploy a registry key using a startup script to disable Internet Explorer 9.

Under `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Setup\9.0` create a key called `DoNotAllowIE90` and set it to **1** for blocked and change it to **0** to unblock it.

[Source](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a6169467-b793-4d17-837d-01776bf2bea4)